# How do I get rid of a ever growing switch-statement?

Tags: java, design-patterns

**The Problem**

```
switch (choice) {
    case 0:
        return new Class0();
    case 1:
        return new Class1();
    case 2:
        return new Class2();
    case <n - 1>:
        return new Class<n - 1>();
    default
        return new Class<n>();
}
```

---

**What I Tried**

Chain of responsibility design pattern. A great and amazing solution for distributing complex tasks. However, I don't want a class that checks if it can do 1 method.

---

**Motivation**

I'm tired of updating the code every time I add something. Bad design.

Comment: Honestly, I've never had anything against long switch blocks. Just move it into it's own method so it is isolated from the rest of your logic. Sometimes you just can't get around having a large selection of inputs to translate.

Comment: Yes. This is the factory pattern after all.

Comment: I think you'll get better answers here if you describe a little more context about what you're actually trying to achieve with this code. The best solution is likely to depend on what's really going on.

Comment: It totally depends on your task/context.

Comment: This is what Head First Design Patterns calls a "Simple Factory". Be aware this has nothing to do with the more famous patterns from the GoF book.

Comment: As long as you have to translate from an int to a type, there is no way around this;  you will need either a `switch` or a Map or some other equivalent translation logic.  What is the origin of those int values?  If possible, I would try to replace the possible choices with objects that each contain the type or a factory method to generate the respective type.

Comment: You could do it with a list of suppliers, i.e. `List.of(Class0::new, Class1::new /* etc */)`, then do `list.get(i).get()`; it's not vastly better (if at all) than a switch though.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that each of `Class0, Class1, ...ClassN` have public non-arg constructor, [`Class::forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) and [`Class::newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) may be used to build a class name, retrieve a class, and instantiate it:

```java
public static final int MAX_CLASS_N = 5; // n limit

public Object getInstance(int x) throws Exception {
    int id = x < 0 || x >= MAX_CLASS_N ? MAX_CLASS_N : x;
    return Class.forName("Class" + id).newInstance();
}
```

Similarly, an array/list of `Class` can be created as a "cache", a helper method replacing a checked `ClassNotFound` exception with a runtime `IllegalArgumentException` is needed:

```java
public static Class<?> classForName(String clazz) {
    try { 
        return Class.forName(clazz); 
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad class name: " + clazz, cex);
    }
}

public static final Class[] BUILDERS = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, MAX_CLASS_N)
        .mapToObj(i -> "Class" + i)
        .map(MyClass::classForName)
        .toArray(Class[]::new);

public static Object buildInstance(int n) throws Exception {
    int id = n < 0 || n >= MAX_CLASS_N ? MAX_CLASS_N : n;

    return BUILDERS[id].newInstance();
}
```

Tests (assuming classes `Class0, Class1, ... Class5` are defined)

```java
System.out.println(getInstance(-1));
System.out.println(getInstance(2));
System.out.println(getInstance(5));
System.out.println("----");
System.out.println(buildInstance(0));
System.out.println(buildInstance(3));
System.out.println(buildInstance(50));
```

Output:

```
Class5@445b84c0
Class2@61a52fbd
Class5@233c0b17
----
Class0@63d4e2ba
Class3@7bb11784
Class5@33a10788
```

Comment: Using reflection for this is a bit grim - you only find out at runtime if it's going to work for a particular N. And this also does presuppose the class names really are just prefix + N, which I would really hope is not the case...!

Comment: Possibly, in real app multiple mappings from a shorter alias to an actual fully-qualified class name exist.   Also, there's a chance that this code should be executed during start-up of the app (e.g. after reading some config files with the mappings) so it should not be a big issue.

Comment: Use `Constructor.newInstance()`, from the docs for `Class#newInstance()`: "Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The Constructor.newInstance method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) InvocationTargetException."

Use `Class.forName(clazz).getConstructor().newInstace()`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your context. If possible you can use constant Map, you still have to register each class using put method, but it's considered cleaner. It has limitation like the dependency injection that must be constant too.

Or if you use Spring, you can create a utils class of Map and use @PostConstruct in your new class to put your new Component class to the utils Map. So registering is at your new class. But it also costs mutable Map and be careful with that.

I don't know your cases. But it's maybe your implementation is too complicated or tightly coupled. Try to look at Abstract Factory Pattern or Bridge Design Pattern if possible to segregate some variants. https://refactoring.guru is one of good source to learn design patterns.

Answer (score -2):

In this example we use instead of the switch expression an enum representing the implementing a class supplier:

```
  interface ProblemSolver{}
  
  public enum Choice implements Supplier<ProblemSolver> {
    ONE(AnyProblemSolver::new),
    TWO(AnyProblemSolver::new)
    ;
    
    private final Supplier<ProblemSolver> supplier;
    
    Choice(Supplier<ProblemSolver> supplier){
      this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    @Override
    public ProblemSolver get() {
      return supplier.get();
    }
  }

  public ProblemSolver getProblemSolver(Choice choice){
    return choice.get();
  }
```

Comment: Seems like just a more complicated and hard to understand way of doing the same thing that has the same issue - you need to modify every time a new choice is added.

Comment: @John3136 but you only have to add it to the enum, somewhere you have to list all options...
Otherwise I only the a package scan like spring does it.

Comment: So explain why adding to an enum  is better than adding to a switch ? You haven't answered the actual question.

Comment: @John3136 because it's much less complex than a switch statement with hundred of cases... Also a Enum is much more self explaining than long switch statement where not each case has a clear naming

Comment: You and I have different definitions of complex !  It is obvious what the switch is doing just by looking - this I have to think about. Ok you can solve that with comments but still...